# Looping over a list of sObjects that has more than object type

Tags: apex, list, sobject

I'm trying to access a field from a list of sObjects which holds 3 different objects types.

```
List<SObject> data  = new List<SObject>();

for (sObject li : data) {
    String sObjName = li.Id.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    system.debug(sObjName);

    if(String.valueOf(sObjName) == 'CR_Contract__c'){
        Month = li.End_Date__c.month(); //Cannot access End_Date__c field
        MonthN = String.valueOf(month);
    }
}
```

How can I access the field to run logic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a better way: the [switch statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm). You can now do this:

```
for(sObject li : data){
  switch on li {
    when CR_Contract__c cr {
      Month = cr.End_Date__c.month();
      ...
    }
    when ... {
      // etc
    }
  }
}
```

This new switch statement will help avoid typos as well, because they will be caught at compile-time.

Comment: oo i'll give that a shot now.

Comment: Surprising the `when TypeName VariableName` mechanism is there: hardly seems like a pressing need.

Comment: @KeithC I've already used it like 4 times this week, and I have like 2 or 3 dozen other near-future uses for it, too. It might seem trivial at first, but once you need it, you'll understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it. I need to convert it to the type of sObject it is before I can access it.

```
if(String.valueOf(sObjName) == 'CR_Contract__c'){
    CR_Contract__c con = (CR_Contract__c)li;
    Month = con.End_Date__c.month();
    MonthN = String.valueOf(month);
}
```